# Редирект аутентифицированного пользователя на laravel

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация

Как изменить адрес редиректа, так, чтобы при авторизации пользователя, его возвращало на страницу, на которой он находился до авторизации. например он находился по адресу `'/shop'` а после авторизации, его возвращало на эту же страницу.

Мой LoginController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating products for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect products after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        return Redirect::back();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

}
```

Comment: Что-то вы нагородили. Показывайте весь код.

Comment: добавил код, но не думаю что это поможет

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй такой подход в контролере:

```php
return redirect()->back();
```

Есть еще такой способ, но я его не использовал:

```php
back();
```

Comment: не работает. 'Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected' вот такое выбрасывает

Comment: Вероятно это именно то, что тебе нужно:  
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954791/laravel-5-after-login-redirect-back-to-previous-page 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login/17990185

Answer (score 0):

LoginController.php

```
 public function showLoginForm()
    {
        session(['link' => url()->previous()]);
        return view('auth.login');
    }


    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect(session('link'));
    }
```

Comment: Я бы добавил пояснений к коду :)